# What should I do to get out of the called function and continue with the other function?

Tags: c++

I have created a struct questions with the element `testQuestion`, `answerQuestion` and point. I also created a void function which is connected to the elements of the struct. When I call the function and input the question, the program does not continue to the other element which is the answer but turns back to input username and password.

Why does this happen?

```
struct professor
{
    string username;
    string password;
};
professor professorData;

struct question
{
    char testQuestion[50];
    char answerQuestion[50];
    int pointQuestion;
};
question questionData;

void readProfessor(professor &professorData)
{
    cout << "Enter the professor username: ";
    cin >> professorData.username;

    cout << "Enter the professor password: ";
    cin >> professorData.password;
    cout << endl;
}
void readQuestion(question &questionData)
{
    cout << "Enter the question: " << endl;
    cin >> questionData.testQuestion;

    cout << "Enter the answers: " << endl;
    cin >> questionData.answerQuestion;
}
void professorMenu()
{
    string pUsername;
    string pPassword;
    cout << "Enter professor username: ";
    cin >> pUsername;
    cout << "Enter professor password: ";
    cin >> pPassword;

    if ((pUsername.compare(professorData.password) == 0) && (pPassword.compare(professorData.password) == 0))
    {
        readQuestion(questionData);
    }
}
```

Calling from here

```
  adminMenu()
{
    int adminUsername = 1234;
    int inputAdminUsername;
    char adminPassword[6] = "admin";
    char inputAdminPassword[6];
    int a;
    string inputStudent[20];
    string inputProfessor[20];

    cout << "Enter admin username: ";
    cin >> inputAdminUsername;
    cout << "Enter admin password: ";
    cin >> inputAdminPassword;

    if (inputAdminUsername == adminUsername && strcmp(adminPassword, inputAdminPassword) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Successful login." << endl;

        do
        {
            cout << "Press 1 to add professor" << endl;
            cout << "Press 2 to add student" << endl;
            cout << "Press 3 to go back to main menu" << endl;
            cin >> a;
            if (a == 1)
            {
                readProfessor(professorData);
            }

            else if (a == 2)
            {
                readStudent(studentData);
            }

            else if (a == 3)
                mainMenu();
        } while (a != 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your main(...) function or wherever you are calling these from?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.